# Google chart image, add labels to the X and Y axis

Tags: google-visualization

I am using:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/

I want to describe that the X is "Meal number" and Y is "calories"

```
chs=440x220
chxt=y,x
cht=lc
chco=3072F3
chd=t:931.4,23.5,572.4,0,0,0,0
chds=0,2500
chxr=0,0,2500|1,1,7,1
chdl=Energi
chdlp=b
chls=2
chma=5,5,5,25
chm=o,000000,0,-1,5
```

You can try and see here:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_playground.html

I already have labels for X and Y. The X axis 1,2,3,4...  and the Y axis 0,250,500...

I want to add at the top or bottom on the Y axis: Calories
And on the X axis: Meal number

I found this:
http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/adding-multiple-axis-labels-to-a-google-chart

But i dont know how to do it on a Line chart

Answer (score 0):

The `chxl` parameter allows you to specify the label and `chxp` enables you to position the labels, e.g.:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart
   ?chxl=0:|Calories||1:|Hours
   &chxp=0,100|1,50
   &chxt=y,x
   &chbh=a
   &chs=300x225
   &cht=bvg
   &chco=A2C180,3D7930
   &chd=t:10,50,60,80,40,60,30|50,60,100,40,20,40,30
   &chtt=Vertical+bar+chart
```

More detail (including how to apply styles to axis labels):

- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#axis_labels

Comment: I already have labels i need extras please see my updated question sorry